# What Query Sets can help me produce results dependent on two Choice Fields?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views, django-queryset

My project has many physics questions stored in its database where each of these questions belongs to a Physics' topic and a Question type.
I have two `ChoiceField`:
* One for topics and includes 16 topics.
* One for question type and includes two question types.

I have a submit button that is supposed to show me the results of my filtering, however, I don't know how to write the Query Sets in the `views.py` although I have read the Documentation but still don't know how to make one query or more to get my results.

This is the `models.py`

```
            from django.db import models
            from home.choices import *

            # Create your models here.

            class Topic(models.Model):
                topic_name = models.IntegerField(
                                choices = question_topic_name_choices, default = 1)
                def __str__(self):
                    return '%s' % self.topic_name

            class Image (models.Model):
                image_file = models.ImageField()

                def __str__(self):
                    return '%s' % self.image_file

            class Question(models.Model):
                question_type = models. IntegerField(
                                choices = questions_type_choices, default = 1)
                question_topic = models.ForeignKey(    'Topic',
                                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                blank=True,
                                                null=True)
                question_description = models.TextField()
                question_answer = models.ForeignKey(    'Answer',
                                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                blank=True,
                                                null=True)
                question_image = models.ForeignKey(    'Image',
                                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                blank=True,
                                                null=True)

                def __str__(self):
                    return '%s' % self.question_type

            class Answer(models.Model):
                answer_description = models.TextField()
                answer_image = models.ForeignKey(    'Image',
                                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                blank=True,
                                                null=True)

                def __str__(self):
                    return '%s' % self.answer_description
```

This is the `forms.py`

```
            from django import forms
            from betterforms.multiform import MultiModelForm
            from .models import Topic, Image, Question, Answer
            from .choices import questions_type_choices, question_topic_name_choices

            class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
                topic_name      =   forms.ChoiceField(
                                choices=question_topic_name_choices,
                                widget = forms.Select(
                                attrs = {'class': 'home-select-one'}
                                    ))

                class Meta:
                    model = Topic
                    fields = ['topic_name',]
                    def __str__(self):
                        return self.fields


            class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
                question_type =   forms.ChoiceField(
                                choices= questions_type_choices,
                                widget = forms.Select(
                                attrs = {'class': 'home-select-two'},
                                    ))

                class Meta:
                    model = Question
                    fields = ['question_type',]
                    def __str__(self):
                        return self.fields


            class QuizMultiForm(MultiModelForm):
                form_classes    =   {
                            'topics':TopicForm,
                            'questions':QuestionForm
                }
```

This is the `views.py`

```
        from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
        from django.views.generic import CreateView, TemplateView
        from home.models import Topic, Image, Question, Answer
        from home.forms import QuizMultiForm

        def QuizView(request):
            if request.method == "POST":
                form = QuizMultiForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    pass
            else:
                form = QuizMultiForm()
            return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form})
```

This is the `index.html`

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit" id="home-Physics-time-button">
    It is Physics Time</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

i dont know what exactly you want to filter or if i understood correctly (cant add comments yet), but here is an example:

views.py

```
def QuizView(request):
               topics = Topic.objects.filter(topic_name=1) # i dont know your choices, but i go with the set default
                if request.method == "POST":
                    form = QuizMultiForm(request.POST)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        pass
                else:
                    form = QuizMultiForm()
                return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form, 'topics':'topics})
```

template part for calling now the query

```
{% for topic in topics %}
<h1> {{ topic.topic_name }} </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

explanation: you are filtering the query in your view by .filter(model_field=)
in your template you iterate trough all results (you are passing 'topics' from the view into the template by the context parameter in your curly brackets), filtered by the view

Comment: My final goal is when I click on the submit button is to go to a different template where its context is the questions stored in the database according to the input done by the user. I know that to do that I have to create a new view and render a template with it. I don't know how to do that, and I would appropriate any help that I could get.
Thank you!

Comment: how to retrieve selected data from Django choice Field? And I have two of them (topics and questions' types)